# How to remove indent from photos (Blocks with photos)?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout and I ran into a problem: 
I do not remove the indent from photos by the standard method.

`body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}`
https://codepen.io/andrew-balashov/pen/NJGvNj

How do you advise to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'indent'? Your problem description is not clear.

Comment: what solution you want??? also give here your full code and site link..

Comment: I attached a photo, there is a white indent between the photos vertically.

Comment: Indentation is probably the wrong word here. You mean `margin` or just `spacing`

Comment: @MohitGupta Be kind, adding multiple question marks can seem rude in some cultures :)

Comment: @A.Balashov can you paste the code or a working demo? The problem can be solved in different ways, but we need to see how exactly you are currently doing it.

Comment: There is a 300 line code, this site does not allow me to insert such a long code

Comment: It is on the local server

Comment: On the attached image there are two background pictures between them a white stripe (indent). How to remove it?

Comment: use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to upload your code.

Comment: In this image, my cursor is exactly on that lane (Indent), which I am trying to remove

Comment: It's really difficult to imagine the structure of html and what kind of css is being used by just looking at the picture. It would be really helpful if you could provide minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/andrew-balashov/pen/NJGvNj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean with indent. Since i think you mean padding/margin and suggerating there are 2 images.

You can add an class element to both images and try setting padding to 0 or margin to 0, if that doesnt work always try !important i dont know if you are using bootstrap, but bootstrap can add standard css to images when using in bootstrap elements.

```
.img{
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Next time, Please provide some code and more info about your problem. This is too wide and can be misunderstood in many ways.

Comment: All the same, it does not work out. Here's the code: https://codepen.io/andrew-balashov/pen/NJGvNj

Comment: @A.Balashov Then you can also try to add a class to the second image ans apply a margin-top: -30px; to it

Comment: @A.Balashovyou should use background images in this case, sth like that but better adjusted to your usecase: ```#oneimg {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487291783462-9d3d36a0cbf1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1482&q=80);
  height: 500px;
}```